# Better Model/Algorithm to predict multiple target

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, prediction

I wanna use multiple variables to predict multiple target.  Note **multiple target** here doesn't mean multi-label.

Let's go for an example like this:

```
# In this example: x1,x2,x3 are used to predict y1,y2

pd.DataFrame({'x1':[1,2,3],'x2':[2,3,4],'x3':[1,1,1],'y1':[1,2,1],'y2':[2,3,3]})

    x1  x2  x3  y1  y2
0   1   2   1   1   2
1   2   3   1   2   3
2   3   4   1   1   3
```

In my limited experience with data mining, I found two solutions might help:

1. Build two xgboost models respectively to predict `y1,y2`
2. Using a full-connected layer to embed `[x1,x2,x3]` into `[y1,y2]`, which seems it's a promising solution.

Wanted to know if it's good practice to do that and what would be the better way to predict multiple target?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your approach, two outputs means you need two functions. I hope it's clear that a layer producing two outputs is equivalent to two layers producing an output each.

The only thing worth taking into account here (only relevant for deeper models) is whether you want to build intermediate representations of your input that are shared for predicting both outputs, i.e. x → h1 → h2 → .. → hN, hN → y1, hN → y2. Doing so would enforce your hN representation to act as a task-indifferent, multi-purpose encoder while simultaneously reducing the complexity of having two models learn the same thing.

For shallow architectures, such as the single-layer one you described, this is meaningless.